# getting correct meaning by analyzing a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, reading-comprehension

I have following paragraph and trying to understand what it clearly mention.

> This paper shows several extensions and discusses the topology
>   approach, while recognizing that reconstruction of height jumps is a
>   challenge (A, 2010; B, 2007) and describing problems related to
>   intersection lines and jump edges between two segments.

first sentence is clear to me. I have problem with while part. It contains that also. So, I am confused. I want to know this and describing.. is related to that or while.

If I simplify my question,

Does the stricture of second part is

> 1. while recognizing (X) and describing (Y) or..
> 2. while recognizing that
>      (P and describing Q).

**UPDATE:**
If I like to modify 1, Would it be possible to use one recognition as while recognizing (X) and (Y). I think yes, But Y is too long, Does this misguide the reader?

Can anyone help me to get the idea of this. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of the second part is:

> 1. while recognizing (X) and describing (Y)

For clarity:

> This paper shows several extensions and discusses the topology
>   approach, while (1) recognizing that reconstruction
>   of height jumps is a challenge (A, 2010; B, 2007), and (2) describing
>   problems related to intersection lines and jump edges between two segments.

**EDIT**: For your second question, I think you're asking for this:

> This paper shows several extensions and discusses the topology
>   approach, while recognizing that (1) reconstruction
>   of height jumps is a challenge (A, 2010; B, 2007), and that (2)
>   problems related to intersection lines and jump edges between two segments
>   *are also challenges*.

Note that in the above paragraph, I have added **"are also challenges"** to the end of (2) in order for the fragment to make some sense.

Comment: thank you, if i want to modify it, can i do it like while recognising (x) and (y) by omiting describing and assuming it is also recognizing. SO, Onerecognizing is enough?

Comment: Yes. In general you can coordinate many different grammatical structures, but they usually must be the same structure. Your 2) in your question attempted to coordinate P which was introduced by _that_ and so must be a clause with a finite verb, and "describing Q" which is not a finite clause and can't follow _that_.